# User input of date

Tags: date

I have searched the web but can't find an answer. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I want to allow the user to input a date and then have a series of if statements to determine what is then displayed on the web page according to which date is specified. I can do the If statements but I can't find a way to enter the date as a variable which is then used to determine what the page displays. I assume I shall need something like Onclick to "refresh" the page. So I want the code to look like this:

input (date)
if date = [date1] then display this
if date = [date2] then display that

Comment: In what [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) are your (trying) to write this, the list is tooo long to make a guess ?

Comment: Seeing you profile.... do: [research: creating a date input in javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=creating+a+date+input+in+javascript), then find [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#try_it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#try_it)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Date Display Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="dateInput">Enter Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="dateInput">
    <button onclick="displayContent()">Show Content</button>
    
    <div id="output">
    </div>

    <script>
        function displayContent() {
            var selectedDate = document.getElementById("dateInput").value;

            var date1 = "2023-12-01";
            var date2 = "2023-12-02";

            var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");

            if (selectedDate === date1) {
                outputDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Display this for Date 1</p>";
            } else if (selectedDate === date2) {
                outputDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Display that for Date 2</p>";
            } else {
                outputDiv.innerHTML = "<p>No content available for the selected date</p>";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```